# How can I create something similar to an alias, that does properly expand to the initial command?

Tags: bash, command-line, alias

I have set up aliases for `apt-get update`, `apt-get install`, and so on. 
Thats quite convenient. But what I really would like to have is something like this:

type `agi` `TAB` `vi` and have it automatically list all packages starting with **vi**, as it would happen when issuing `apt-get install` `TAB` `vi`.

Would something like this be achievable somehow, maybe by writing a little script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash programmable completion is something I haven't bothered much with myself, but I believe this will do what you want (NB assumes bash version 4.0 or newer. If you run Ubuntu 10.04 or newer, you're good.):

```
alias agi='apt-get install'
_agi_completion() { 
    mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <(apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}")
}
complete -F _agi_completion agi
```

*Programmable Completion* in bash's manual explains how it works, though it's quite complex.

Comment: +1, it also works prepending sudo

Comment: uhm, I should correct my preceding comment: completion works with sudo prepended, but alias is not found, once you hit enter

Comment: @enzotib, yes, sudo has no knowledge of shell functions or aliases, only the shell deals with those. I'm guessing the alias is actually `alias agi='sudo apt-get install'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your aliases to the shell completion dictionaries so it knows what it is completing for those commands. The shell completions should already be named functions, but you have to tell it that they apply to your new command names.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this answer? Maybe add a step by step guide?

Comment: I only know step by step for zsh, not bash. Maybe it will put somebody on the right track that knows bash, otherwise I'll try to research it later.

Comment: I was trying to google shell completion dictionaries but could not find anything useful as a starting point. 
Is there a certain location in the fs where I could look for those dictionaries?

Comment: Do you have a "bash-completions" package? If not look through the files included with the "bash" package and see if you can make out which one have completion definitions.